# How to show int value

Tags: flutter, dart

Int values for price will not show on the app in the `ProgrammesCard`. Which way is best to solve this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../constants.dart';

class ProgrammesCard extends StatelessWidget {
  List<_ProgrammesCard> _programmes() {
    return [
      _ProgrammesCard(
        title: 'PROGRAMMES',
        price: 'FROM £30',
        period: '6-WEEK \nPROGRAMME',
        imageURL: 'assets/images/programmes/kane.png',
      ),
      _ProgrammesCard(
        title: 'INDIVIDUAL ZOOM',
        price: 'FROM £15 \nPER PLAYER',
        period: 'EACH SESSION',
        imageURL: 'assets/images/programmes/traore.jpeg',
      ),
      _ProgrammesCard(
        title: 'GROUP ZOOM',
        price: 'FROM £5 \nPER PLAYER',
        period: 'EACH SESSION',
        imageURL: 'assets/images/programmes/wolves.png',
      ),
      _ProgrammesCard(
        title: 'PRIMAL FLOW',
        price: 'FROM £5 \nPER PLAYER',
        period: 'EACH SESSION',
        imageURL: 'assets/images/programmes/podence.jpeg',
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        height: 270,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 5, 5, 5),
          children: _programmes().map<Widget>((photo) {
            return _ProgrammesGridItem(programmesCard: photo);
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ProgrammesCard {
  _ProgrammesCard({
    this.imageURL,
    this.title,
    this.price,
    this.period,
  });
  final String imageURL;
  final String title;
  final String price;
  final String period;
}

class _ProgrammesText extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ProgrammesText(this.text, this.fontSize);
  final String text;
  final double fontSize;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Cocogoose',
          fontSize: fontSize,
          color: kProgrammeTextColor),
    );
  }
}

class _ProgrammesGridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  _ProgrammesGridItem({Key key, @required this.programmesCard})
      : super(key: key);

  final _ProgrammesCard programmesCard;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Card(
            semanticContainer: true,
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: kClub2Color,
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                        child: RotatedBox(
                          quarterTurns: 3,
                          child: _ProgrammesText(programmesCard.title, 14),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                        width: 10,
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            height: 40,
                            child: VerticalDivider(
                              color: kProgrammeTextColor,
                              thickness: 1,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    _ProgrammesText(programmesCard.price, 10),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                _ProgrammesText(programmesCard.period, 8),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        programmesCard.imageURL,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 250,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPm0S.jpg)

Comment: The price is showing up for me. The type of the `price` attribute is String. Did you mean to change it to int?

Comment: @FDuhen was right, it was the Custom Font 'Cocogoose' that wouldn't accept integers. Dart/Flutter was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay.
I'm pretty sure your problem here is linked with the custom font `Cocogoose` you're using.
Double check that you correctly integrated the *.ttf files containing the Numbers of the font and you should be fine !

Comment: You were right! Been trying several ways thinking I'm going crazy! Thanks